# Rename SMB Servers

Tags: macos, network, mount, smb

I have 2 SMB servers that I connect to on a daily basis. One is my development server and the other is my production server. Both of them are a little different in the folder structure.

When they are mounted, they take the names of the folder you are mounting. Both servers are mounted on the same folder name so its really hard to tell the difference.

Is it possible to change the name of a mounted SMB server? I would like to just have "Development" and "Live".

Comment: How do you mount your SMB-shares?

Comment: I usually use finder and click GO > Connect to server > smb://xx.xx.xx.xxx. I am all for doing it another way if its possible to give an alias.

Comment: then you have to adjust it on the server side (Windows? Linux? Apple?)

Comment: It's windows but I figured renaming should be an option or creating a shortcut to it somehow and have that with a custom name.

Answer (score 2):

1. **auto_fs method**

The two shares will be mounted automatically.

Please create a Share folder and two folders `Development` and `Live` inside of that in your User folder and change your auto_master with `sudo nano /etc/auto_master` to

**/etc/auto_master**

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master                        # Use directory service
/-                                  auto_smb    -nosuid
/net                                -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home                               auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers                    -fstab
/-                                  -static
```

and create a file  with `sudo touch /etc/auto_smb` and add with `sudo nano /etc/auto_smb` the content

**/etc/auto_smb**

```
/Users/username/Share/Development -fstype=smbfs,noowners,soft ://user:password@dev-server_ip/Shared_Folder
/Users/username/Share/Live -fstype=smbfs,noowners,soft ://user:password@prod-server_ip/Shared_Folder
```

for AD-members

```
/Users/username/Share/Development -fstype=smbfs,noowners,soft ://DOMAIN\;user:password@dev-server_ip/Shared_Folder
/Users/username/Share/Live -fstype=smbfs,noowners,soft ://DOMAIN\;user:password@prod-server_ip/Shared_Folder
```

*Both files ("auto＿master" & "auto＿smb") need a trailing empty line*

change the file root only readable:

`sudo chown 600 /etc/auto_smb`

enter `sudo automount -vc` in Terminal with the output:

```
$ sudo automount -vc
automount: /Users/username/Share/Development updated
automount: /Users/username/Share/Live updated
automount: /net updated
automount: /home updated
automount: no unmounts
```

Please regard the output: **/Users/username/Share/Development or Live updated**

*(I've tested this with Mac OS X 10.10.1 (as client) & Windows Server 2012 R (Active Directory) in a VirtualLab. It worked without any problems and survived any restart. The following workarounds weren't necessary for me.)*

If the shares aren't mounted with correct access rights (e.g. root only) you may have to unmount it with `sudo umount /Users/.../shares`and remount it with `cd /User/.../shares.

An automatic approach with launchd is the [following solution](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25321298#25321298):

Create a script:

```
while ! mount | grep "map auto_smb on /Users/user/Share  
do  
        sleep 2  
done  

if ! mount | grep "mount .* mounted by user"  
then  
        sudo umount /Users/user/Share/Development
        sudo umount /Users/user/Share/Live
        sudo -u user cd /Users/user/Share/Development  
        sudo -u user cd /Users/user/Share/Live
fi
```

(i don't know if line 1 in the script is correct)

and save it somewhere e.g. `/Users/user/bin/remount.sh`.

To call the script as a LaunchDaemon, you have to create a plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
<plist version="1.0">  
<dict>  
          <key>Label</key>  
          <string>com.organization.remount</string>  
          <key>ProgramArguments</key>  
          <array>  
                    <string>/Users/user/bin/remount.sh</string>  
          </array>  
          <key>RunAtLoad</key>  
          <true/>  
</dict>  
</plist>
```

The string com.organization.remount is also the name you will have to give the file, with the extension plist: "com.organization.remount.plist".

The string /Users/user/bin/remount.sh is the path to where you saved your script.

**2. Windows Server2008r2 command line-method** (if you have admin rights and access to the servers)

really quick and dirty: `net share <sharename=drive:path>`

Example:
net share Live=C:\Data (on the production server)
net share Development=C:\Data (on the development server)

Comment: I did this and both show up in the users folder with their respective names and go to the correct place. Is there a way to create a shortcut now for these to be on the desktop?

Comment: sure. just make 2 aliases

Comment: Hmm, after restarting the folders still show up but when I click them, they don't connect at all.

Comment: hmm i've updated the auto_master auto_smb -> auto_smb -nosuid. run "sudo automount -vc" again afterwards

Comment: Is it required to use the user:pass in the file? I didn't use it on mine as it wasn't required when I did it through "Connect to Server".

Comment: are these your servers or company servers?

Comment: They are the company but the credentials are based on existing permissions on the folders I am accessing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19148/discussion-between-klanomath-and-sbb).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one suggestion: https://superuser.com/questions/775539/custom-names-for-smb-shares-on-osx

I've used a similar method to mount volumes using sshfs to particular mount points for iTunes and calibre and the like.